# Given a dataset with one datapoint and two columns concat in another df where two columns are vectors?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called config in which there is one datapoint and two columns and I want convert the length of the config file to a dataframe of a length of another df called data. So I can concat it easy.

```
def create_csv():       
    """
    Wir haben unsere Bohrdaten als parquet Dateien gegeben und müssen nun diese entpacken und anschließend als csv speichern. 
    Zu unseren Bohrdaten kommen Config Dateien hinzu, in der die Bohrparameter angegeben sind. 
    Diese berücksichtigen wir ebenso in unserem Trainingsdatensatz, da diese wichtige Faktoren zur 
    Wärmeentwicklung beim Bohren sind. Die Spalte Feed gibt die Vorschubgeschwindigkeit,
    die für diesen Bohrvorgang verwendet wird, wieder. Unter RPM verstehen wir die Umdrehungen pro Minute. 
    Diese beiden Faktoren haben einen enormen Einfluss auf die Wärmeleifähigkeit. 
    


    """

    path_data = './rawdata'
    count = 0
    for subdir in os.listdir(path_data):
        subdir_path = os.path.join(path_data, subdir)
        if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
            # Load the Parquet file into a Pandas DataFrame
            df_parquet = pq.read_table(os.path.join(subdir_path, 'data.parquet')).to_pandas()

            # Load the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
            df_csv = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(subdir_path, 'config.csv'))

            # Select the desired columns from the CSV file 
            df_csv1 =  df_csv[['RPM','Feed']]

            #df_csv1 need to be reshaped to a df with length of df_parqet, so where each is a constant value ?

            # Concatenate the DataFrames along the columns axis
            df_concatenated = pd.concat([df_parquet, df_csv1], axis=1)

            # Save the concatenated DataFrame as a CSV file
            df_concatenated.to_csv(os.path.join("rawdata_csv", 'raw_csv_data' + str(count) +'.csv'), index=False)
    
            count = count + 1
```